# Techniques for Dealing with the Integral of 1/ln(x)

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

I have a differential equation which is of the form 
$$\frac {dy}{dx} = a\ln(y) + by$$
 and the more I look for the solution, the more I find strange solutions. Can anyone explain why this equation is so obscure? And what might be some techniques for solving.

Comment: Integral of $1/\ln(x)$ is not an elemantary function, it is a function called logarithmic integral.

Comment: Hint: you have an autonomous differential equation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

Comment: I doubt there's a closed form for the integral:$\int \frac{1}{b x+a \log (x)} \, dx=\int_0^{\infty } -x^{1-a t} E_{a t}(b t x) \, dt$ where $ E_{a t}(b t x) $ is  exponential integral function.